# AWS SES - high Bounce rate and sending paused

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ses

Right now every time I try to send an email, the AWS SES service return 554 due to high bounce rate (18.55%), and my account status is shutdown also the sending is paused.

So what can I do to enable the sending back and to reduce the bounce rate?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if your account has been blocked from sending email due to excessive bounces, which is interpreted as a sign that you are not complying with SES's requirements that you send only high quality email to people who actually want to receive it, and that you actively monitor bounces and inmediately stop sending to invalid addresses.

Review the documentation, specifically [Amazon SES Sending Review Process FAQs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/e-faq.html) in the *Amazon Simple Email Service Developer Guide*, for a full description of the Sending Review Process that occurs when SES detects problematic patterns in your mail sending, such as a high bounce rate.

Comment: Thank you Michael, but I already checked that article.

Comment: That article is the definitive reference on the subject.  Its advice seems clear.  You need to identify the reason why you sent so many emails to invalid addresses, you need to formulate and document a plan to prevent it from happening again, and you need to contact SES about the matter using the contact information provided there.  If this doesn't address your issue, then which part is the obstacle?